# How to Check if a String has the same characters in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Let say I've String

`var str = 'Sumur Bandung'`

and

`var x = 'Kecamatan Sumur Bandung'`

from `str` and `x` there are two matching characters `Sumur` and `Bandung`. How can I check that `str` has characters that match with `x`?

Comment: `console.log(x.indexOf(str))` `console.log(x.includes(str))`

Comment: Duplicate of [How to check whether a string contains a substring in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-to-check-whether-a-string-contains-a-substring-in-javascript)

Comment: @CanUver I've try `includes` doesnt work result always `false`

Comment: `'Kecamatan Sumur Bandung'.includes('Sumur Bandung')` returns true for me. If you're getting false then one of the strings isn't what you think it is.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery source is `Sumur Bandung` not `Kecamantan Sumur Bandung`

Comment: @RimuruTempest I'm not sure what you're trying to say. Obviously the shorter string can't contain the longer one.

Comment: Reading your question again, are you trying to check if both strings have at least one *word* in common?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let str = "Sumur Bandung";
let x = "Kecamatan Sumur Bandung";

function stringContains(parentString, childString) {
  const parentStringSeparator = parentString.split(" ");
  return childString
  .split(" ")
  .every((word) => parentStringSeparator.includes(word));
}

console.log(stringContains(x, str));
```

If I understand you correctly, this is what you're asking. Given a parent string separated by spaces, check if every word of a child string is in the parent string.

Edit: This function doesn't take in account word order and splits every string with spaces.

Edit2: If you're trying to ask whether a child string contains at least **one** word from a parent string, you should use some instead of every:

```
let str = "Sumur Bandung";
let x = "Kecamatan Sumur Bandung";

function stringContains(parentString, childString) {
  const parentStringSeparator = parentString.split(" ");
  return childString
  .split(" ")
  .some((word) => parentStringSeparator.includes(word));
}

console.log(stringContains(x, str));
```

Comment: finally some one can understand what i mean because Iam not speak english. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use "`include`", it's the best.

```js
var x = 'Kecamatan Sumur Bandung'
var str = 'Sumur Bandung'
console.log(x.includes(str) || str.includes(x))
```

Comment: source is `Sumur Bandung` not `Kecamatan Sumur Bandung`

Comment: I mean `'Sumur Bandung'.includes('Kecamatan Sumur Bandung')` always return `false`.  because in the future I do not know whether the `Kecamatan` is in the first variable or in the second variable

Comment: @RimuruTempest If the problem is that you don't know which one is the full string then just test both. So using this example that would be `x.includes(str) || str.includes(x)`.